# Google Workspace Addon: Unable to retrigger the onEventOpenTrigger Event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I currently have a `onEventOpenTrigger` that returns a card with informations from the server as well as information from the event itself.

The problem I am facing is that I can edit the server info as well as info from the event. So I want to render the Card with the updated info every time I reopen the event.

Now I am able to rerender the card by using a different trigger `eventUpdateTrigger` that helps me re render the card in case theres a change in members or a change in conference solutions. But I can't seem to retrigger it when I change the time.

Does anyone has any better idea than a refresh button to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Times of the event (start and end) are not supported by Calendar event triggers.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/building-calendar-interfaces#updating_calendar_events), `eventUpdateTrigger` will only be triggered if:

```
 - Adds one or more attendees.
 - Removes one or more attendees.
 - Adds or switches to a different conferencing solution.
```

There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/184761448) on Google's Issue Tracker asking for the date/time fields to be supported. You can click on `+1` to give more priority to it and to receive updates.

In the current situation, the refresh button seems to be the best option for your case.